# Selenium test have JavaScript error only when use firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium, firefox

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGf88.jpg)

```
1477958850279   Marionette  INFO    startBrowser acf6834e-f12d-45f6-b959-    d8cb2ba04916
Nov 01, 2016 11:07:30 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
JavaScript error: http://toolsqa.com/wp-content/themes/dt-the7/js/above-the-fold.min.js?ver=3.8.1, line 1: TypeError: jQuery.browser is undefined
JavaScript error: http://toolsqa.com/wp-content/themes/dt-the7/js/main.min.js?ver=3.8.1, line 7: TypeError: t.browser is undefined
```

Hi Please have a look at the image, I am not sure why this happen since it is only happening if I use Firefox. I have tried chrome, and it doesn't have any error. However, Firefox has fire path and firebug, I have to use Firefox, would someone tell me is this usual? and how should I fix it?

Thank you so much